# Google Maps Closing infowindow auto centers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, center, infowindow

I've added a map to my site using Google Maps API V3.
I've got everything working except this:
how do i get the map to auto center when i close the info window?
sample code :

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.0, -1.0);

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
map.setCenter(myLatlng); 
});
```

really stuck and would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
   map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have some mistake somewhere in your code, because it works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/SZ3XC/

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'ahoj'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.0, -1.0);

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
     map.setCenter(myLatlng); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the jsfiddle. I got it to work on my map as well as added an option to zoom back out to the full map when clicking off the infowindow. Here's an example:

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(0,22); 

`google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
map.setCenter(mapCenter); 
var opt = { zoom: 2};
map.setOptions(opt);
});`
```